# Code highlighting clarification

Tags: support, code-formatting, source-code

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313014/internet-explorer-7-8-content-type-issues-in-meta-tag), I have marked portion of html code and below another one. But the first code line is not being highlighted. Why are they behaving different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first HTML tag is denoted with backticks (`):

```
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`
```

Code tagged with backticks is never highlighted by prettify; only code blocks indented with four spaces per line are highlighted:

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

And for the record, your post isn't as well-formatted as it can be. Paragraphs need to be separated with two line breaks, for one thing. It's also not a good idea to mix HTML with Markdown as it can get frustrating for others to edit. Consider revisiting https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax for help with formatting your posts properly.

Comment: can you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314132/gwt-suggestbox-with-placeholder-attribute/9314367#9314367 , as well but it does not have such symbol